# Parsing Apple JSON

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Normally i'm parsing JSON feeds like (EXAMPLE) ;

```
{
    "AppStore": [
        {
            "Application": "Game",
            "KeyID": "zero"
        }
    ]
}
```

In my JSON i'm doing then

```
NSArray* Parse = [json objectForKey:@"AppStore"];
```

But i now want to parse the JSON of the AppStore it has an other structure

http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=387633954

```
{
    "resultCount": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "kind": "software",
            "features": [
                "gameCenter",
                "iosUniversal"
            ],
            "supportedDevices": [
                "all"
            ],
            "isGameCenterEnabled": true,
            "artistViewUrl": "http://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/mcsebi/id387633957?uo=4",
            "artworkUrl60": "http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/072/Purple/v4/98/a6/56/98a656e8-666a-89ab-c8f0-878b61b9f8f2/Icon.png",
            "screenshotUrls": [
                "http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/076/Purple/v4/fe/36/80/fe3680ae-5439-a2f1-6675-d3246b64f333/mza_11015238406403423.png",
                "http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/099/Purple/v4/73/98/1c/73981cbf-fb79-dc38-9dac-61ab46c2ac60/mzl.gzibbhfx.png",
                "http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/103/Purple/v4/72/b6/87/72b68713-7e5a-f675-83c3-85c2f0e96df1/mzl.gykakuht.png",
                "http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/113/Purple/v4/fa/d6/c4/fad6c453-9da5-2506-2b06-42ed5ff6bd63/mzl.hqbrlhog.png",
                "http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/120/Purple/v4/9e/7a/13/9e7a1388-5089-11e7-0c03-3d1868abbb82/mzl.jogfcyqv.png"
            ],
            "ipadScreenshotUrls": [
                "http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/096/Purple/v4/1f/5a/92/1f5a9249-03b8-90dc-8226-18b1785d5f7d/mzl.ilqgfose.1024x1024-65.jpg",
                "http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/070/Purple/v4/79/74/6b/79746ba8-7ea0-6e81-93d0-9e2493412e21/mzl.saleskru.1024x1024-65.jpg",
                "http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/068/Purple/v4/12/38/91/1238914f-7387-9c9e-06e4-11a55871b04a/mzl.qmiockwv.1024x1024-65.jpg",
                "http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/091/Purple/v4/3b/cf/62/3bcf62e6-4d84-4fc0-e721-c328361f5c95/mzl.somobtxy.1024x1024-65.jpg",
                "http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/074/Purple/v4/e9/d3/e7/e9d3e7b7-b52c-e204-e4b6-1ab5de79e85a/mzl.nedztyfk.1024x1024-65.jpg"
            ],
            "artworkUrl512": "http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/115/Purple/v4/0d/9c/ec/0d9cec04-91b3-5fe2-fa40-100660250f4a/mzl.kavmnegm.png",
            "artistId": 387633957,
            "artistName": "McSebi",
            "price": 0.99,
            "version": "1.2",
            "description": "Connect M is a simple, but very addictive puzzle game. Connect two tiles of the same color and try to remove all the tiles within a time limit. Connect M features:\n \n· 37 levels in 9 worlds. Each world has a new feature\n· High quality graphics\n· High quality sound effects and soundtrack\n\nFollow us on Twitter: http://twitter.com/qt_games\n\nMany customers demanded to save a game explicitely.\nNow you can do it by pressing the disk icon after pausing a game.",
            "genreIds": [
                "6014",
                "7003",
                "7012"
            ],
            "releaseDate": "2010-08-24T02:46:16Z",
            "sellerName": "Sebastian Wegner",
            "currency": "USD",
            "genres": [
                "Games",
                "Arcade",
                "Puzzle"
            ],
            "bundleId": "com.mcsebi.connectm",
            "trackId": 387633954,
            "trackName": "Connect M",
            "primaryGenreName": "Games",
            "primaryGenreId": 6014,
            "releaseNotes": "Level selection:\nYou can now choose to start the game in every world you completed at least once.",
            "wrapperType": "software",
            "trackCensoredName": "Connect M",
            "trackViewUrl": "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/connect-m/id387633954?mt=8&uo=4",
            "contentAdvisoryRating": "4+",
            "artworkUrl100": "http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/115/Purple/v4/0d/9c/ec/0d9cec04-91b3-5fe2-fa40-100660250f4a/mzl.kavmnegm.png",
            "languageCodesISO2A": [
                "DE",
                "EN",
                "IT",
                "NL"
            ],
            "fileSizeBytes": "24434872",
            "sellerUrl": "http://www.mcsebi.com",
            "trackContentRating": "4+"
        }
    ]
}
```

If i do;

```
NSArray* Parse = [json objectForKey:@"resultCount"]; or 
NSArray* Parse = [json objectForKey:@"results"];
```

The App is Crashing:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x352b888f 0x366df259 0x352b8789 0x352b87ab 0x311c05b3 0x8c9e3 0x352171fb 0x3116e747 0x3528cad3 0x3528c29f 0x3528b045 0x3520e4a5 0x3520e36d 0x3650a439 0x32304e7d 0x807a5 0x80240)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Edit:

```
@interface NSDictionary(JSONCategories)
+(NSDictionary*)dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONURLString:(NSString*)urlAddress;
-(NSData*)toJSON;
@end

@implementation NSDictionary(JSONCategories)
+(NSDictionary*)dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONURLString:(NSString*)urlAddress
{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlAddress] ];
    __autoreleasing NSError* error = nil;
    id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if (error != nil) return nil;
    return result;
}

-(NSData*)toJSON
{
    NSError* error = nil;
    id result = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if (error != nil) return nil;
    return result;    
}
@end
```

//

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {

    NSError* error;
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                                             options:kNilOptions 
                                                               error:&error];
        NSArray* UrlParse = [json objectForKey:@"resultCount"]; 

        NSDictionary* SParse = [urlParse objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: How is `json` constructed in each case?

Comment: Maybe try doing it with JSONKit. It would almost certainly be faster, but I've found it is more reliable when these kinds of problems pop up.

Comment: The error message seems to be pretty clear. `responseData` is `nil`. Your problem is apparently not with parsing but with downloading the data.

Comment: @omz: You should make that an answer.

Comment: As a side note, the dictionary's object for `resultCount` is a number, not an array.

Comment: Any help how to parse a number @PeterHosey

Comment: @Jones: The JSON interpreter will do that for you once you start handing it data.

Comment: Yes but the problem is what line of code do i need to have to parse the data in the Apple JSON? That's the problem `{
"resultCount": 1,
"results": [
{` how do i need to do that?     `NSArray* AppStoreUrlParse = [json objectForKey:@"resultCount.results"];` @PeterHosey

Comment: Are you aware that Apple reject applications that scrape their servers for information?

Comment: Why the put an JSON on the web if so it's a API @Jim

Comment: @Jones: Just because they make a JSON API doesn't mean they intend for *you* to use it. Unless they document it somewhere on developer.apple.com, they meant it only for their own use and, as such, they may change or remove it at any time.

Comment: @Jones: You already have the code (in two places) to parse the data. What you need to do is provide it the data to parse. And why have you changed it to `NSArray *AppStoreUrlParse = [json objectForKey:@"resultCount.results"]`? That's even more wrong, in at least three ways. (The dictionary doesn't contain a key named `resultCount.results`; if you meant to get the `results` of the `resultCount`, it doesn't have one, because numbers don't contain anything; even if a number did have a property you'd want, it wouldn't be an array.)

Comment: @PeterHosey Hmm thanks but i don't get it, is there a way to parse the data from here? http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=387633954 for example how can i parse the 'price' with the code i got right now? Is there a way to do this? I can't parse the number because it isn't a array but what now? What do i need to do change to let it work? Any tips? Oh and i didn't change anything just a question

Comment: @Jones: Yes: Get the data, then pass it to the JSON deserializer. The latter step is what you're not doing. You're passing `nil` to it instead. As my answer says, you need to find out why.

Comment: @Jim The guidelines also state that "Applications may use approved Apple RSS feeds such as the iTunes Store RSS feed". Even though this isn't an RSS feed, it's an official API and definitely not "scraping". There are, in fact, several podcast clients in the App Store that use this API.

Comment: "resultCount" isn't an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message says that `responseData` is `nil`, so it's not really a JSON parsing problem.

As you don't show how you construct `responseData`, I don't know what the actual problem is, but it happens before you attempt to parse it.

Comment: @Jones -- Have you considered using the debugger??

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlAddress] ];
> __autoreleasing NSError* error = nil;
> id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
> ```

Two things:

1. Make sure that `urlAddress` truly describes a URL and not a path. If it's a path, use `fileURLWithPath:` to create the NSURL object. (You probably don't have this problem, since you're trying to get info from the App Store, but future readers who are trying to read JSON from a local file may be making this mistake.)
2. Make sure that the URL or path (whichever it is) is correct and describes a thing that exists. Trying to get the contents of a resource that doesn't exist would explain why `data` is `nil`.

Also, you should use the debugger to verify which of your two JSON-to-object methods are producing the exception. Either one of these could be it. The above is for your `+[NSDictionary(JSONCategories) dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONURLString:]`; if the exception is coming from `fetchedData:`, then it means you're calling `fetchedData:` with `nil`, and you should edit your question to show the code that calls `fetchedData:` and how that code gets (or tries to get) the data.